# Mailchimp does not show subscribers for a segment

Tags: c#, mailchimp

I am a C#.net programmer and using MCAPI.Net to add subscribers to the mailchimp subscribers list. I see a strange behavior Or this might be lack of knowledge when I try to view subscribers for a segment. Following is the description:

When I add subscriber's location using MCAPI.net, it gets reflected in the subscribers list of mailchimp, but strangely segment created for that location does not show the added subscriber, it always shows the count 0. For example, I added a USA location like below:

```
Dictionary<string, string> latLongInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();
latLongInfo.Add("LATITUDE", "42.742020");
latLongInfo.Add("LONGITUDE", "-73.767870");
merge["MC_LOCATION"] = latLongInfo;
```

Added subscriber's details shows the location in US but Segment created with filter "**Where location is in USA**" shows 0 subscriber.  Why is it showing 0 when there is a subscriber with the location in USA?

Comment: Can you find it when looking for US state "New York"?

Comment: Yes, I can find it. In fact segment filter is more generic as it says "Location is in USA" regardless of which state it is in.

Comment: That segment you're trying to find the sub in, are you viewing that through the website, or through the API? And if you add a subscriber in, say, France, does it have the same issue?

Comment: I am trying to view that through mailchimp website. If you could try with some other country, say USA or Australia, you might see the issue.

Comment: I don't have a mailchimp account, and creating one really quick would look weird here at work. If you add a subscriber that lives somewhere in Paris, do you get the same issue? And do you get the issue if you add him using an address?

Comment: I just added a subscriber with Paris coordinates, I get the same issue. Segment filter is "Where location is in France", I have a subscriber with in the country "France", but it shows 0 subscribers, even it is set to Auto Update.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that MCAPI.NET is based on the deprecated 1.3 API (unless you found a more recent version).

I think what happens is that the location segment filter uses the postal address to find the subscriber, not the geographical coordinates. Linking a coordinate to the proper country is tricky, and with the many disputed territories can stir up a storm.

Try setting the address mergevar as well. You might have to use a geolocation service for that.